# sudo: restart: command not found

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to follow "Linux OpenVPN GUI Setup Tutorial" from [here](https://zpn.im/setup) to setup vpn on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

I've followed the steps still 3. But on step 4, when I type "sudo restart network-manager" I get an error "sudo: restart: command not found". My network-manager isn't running and I can't proceed further.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It's `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` or `sudo service network-manager restart`.  You're just missing part of the command.

Comment: When I type it, it seems like nothing happens. Compared to the tutorial, I don't see anything like "network-manager start/running process 1844".  Why so?

Comment: @ApoorvPatne Tutorial seems to be very old. I believe many things have changed since.

Comment: The link mentioned in the question. At the bottom, there's a "Linux OpenVPN GUI Setup Tutorial", right above ZPN box. 
Edit : so what could be the right way to do it in Ubuntu 18.04? I'm totally clueless.

Comment: @ApoorvPatne Right way is in the answer. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, how? The tutorial is outdated, right? So what changes should I make to get vpn setup done?

Comment: @ApoorvPatne I guess only the command was outdated. I looked the whole tutorial and everything else seems to be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87125/discussion-between-apoorv-patne-and-kulfy).